# How to transpose columns into rows using SQL

Tags: sql, transpose

I'm creating a view to select just the data I need from a specific table, mainly consting of casting, substringing and aliasing, so that the fields are a specific name, type and length.

```
| Column A | Column B || Question1| Question2|
| -------- | -------- || -------- | -------- |
| ID1      | Cell 2   || A1       | A2       |
| ID2      | Cell 3   || A1       | A2       |
```

My challenge now is that my view needs 2 more fields which are currently spread across 12 or so rows (Questions 1-12).

What I want to achieve is something like below:

```
| Column A | Column B || Question | Answer   |
| -------- | -------- || -------- | -------- |
| ID1      | Cell 2   || Q1       | A1       |
| ID1      | Cell 3   || Q2       | A2       |
| ID1      | Cell 4   || Q3       | A3       |
| ID1      | Cell 5   || Q4       | A4       |
| ID2      | Cell 6   || Q1       | A1       |
| ID2      | Cell 7   || Q2       | A2       |
| ID2      | Cell 8   || Q3       | A3       |
| ID2      | Cell 9   || Q4       | A4       |
```

Is this achievable using SQL in my view?

I'm thinking of using `case` statements but seem to be struggling with this.

Comment: Your question is not overly clear. Is your goal to add the ID2 values to your table? I'm not seeing rows here and I suspect you don't need transpose, you just need joins. Please update your question to be more specific and add some additional information like how you are getting the table provided, where the data in that table comes from, and precisely what you want your result to look like. Providing a minimal reproducible example is a great place to start

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q1' as Question, [Q1] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q2' as Question, [Q2] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q3' as Question, [Q3] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q4' as Question, [Q3] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q5' as Question, [Q1] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q6' as Question, [Q2] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q7' as Question, [Q3] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q8' as Question, [Q3] as Answer from origin
union all 
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q9' as Question, [Q1] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q10' as Question, [Q2] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q11' as Question, [Q3] as Answer from origin
union all
select [Column A], [Column B], 'Q12' as Question, [Q3] as Answer from origin
```